# Forge a DNS response

Tags: networking, dns, wifi, wireshark, scapy

I use scapy to intercept DNS request and forge a response. The interception and forging parts work fine, and it seems that the sending of the forged packet works (at least I can see the dot indicating the success of the `sendp` function). But, on the target station I don't receive the packet -- or I don't see it on Wireshark.

I don't know where my problem is, but I guess it is not in the DNS/UDP part (the packet would be visible in Wireshark). So it's probably in the 802.11 or IP layers.

Here is a request:

```
192.168.2.117 (a4:4e:31:5c:54:78) -> 194.2.0.50 (00:14:d1:ad:9f:88)
DNS request for www.youtube.com.
###[ RadioTap dummy ]###
version   = 0
pad       = 0
len       = 38
present   = TSFT+Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+b14+b29+Ext
notdecoded= ' \x08\x00\xa0 \x08\x00\x00\xc8+\xa3\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10l\x9e\t\xc0\x00\xd5\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x00\xd4\x01'
###[ 802.11 ]###
 subtype   = 8L
 type      = Data
 proto     = 0L
 FCfield   = to-DS
 ID        = 11264
 addr1     = 00:14:d1:ad:9f:88
 addr2     = a4:4e:31:5c:54:78
 addr3     = 00:25:9c:9a:aa:b1
 SC        = 4272
 addr4     = None
###[ 802.11 QoS ]###
    TID       = 0L
    EOSP      = 0L
    Ack Policy= 0L
    Reserved  = 0L
    TXOP      = 0
###[ LLC ]###
       dsap      = 0xaa
       ssap      = 0xaa
       ctrl      = 3
###[ SNAP ]###
          OUI       = 0x0
          code      = 0x800
###[ IP ]###
             version   = 4L
             ihl       = 5L
             tos       = 0x0
             len       = 61
             id        = 213
             flags     = 
             frag      = 0L
             ttl       = 128
             proto     = udp
             chksum    = 0xb489
             src       = 192.168.2.117
             dst       = 194.2.0.50
             \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
                sport     = 50648
                dport     = domain
                len       = 41
                chksum    = 0x7b3c
###[ DNS ]###
                   id        = 64118
                   qr        = 0L
                   opcode    = QUERY
                   aa        = 0L
                   tc        = 0L
                   rd        = 1L
                   ra        = 0L
                   z         = 0L
                   rcode     = ok
                   qdcount   = 1
                   ancount   = 0
                   nscount   = 0
                   arcount   = 0
                   \qd        \
                    |###[ DNS Question Record ]###
                    |  qname     = 'www.youtube.com.'
                    |  qtype     = A
                    |  qclass    = IN
                   an        = None
                   ns        = None
                   ar        = None
###[ Padding ]###
                      load      = '\xb2\x17\xa3\x8a'
```

And the forged response:

```
###[ RadioTap dummy ]###
version   = 0
pad       = 0
len       = 38
present   = TSFT+Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+b14+b29+Ext
notdecoded= ' \x08\x00\xa0 \x08\x00\x00\xc8+\xa3\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10l\x9e\t\xc0\x00\xd5\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x00\xd4\x01'
###[ 802.11 ]###
 subtype   = 8L
 type      = Data
 proto     = 0L
 FCfield   = from-DS
 ID        = 11264
 addr1     = a4:4e:31:5c:54:78
 addr2     = 00:14:d1:ad:9f:88
 addr3     = 00:25:9c:9a:aa:b1
 SC        = 14272
 addr4     = None
###[ 802.11 QoS ]###
    TID       = 0L
    EOSP      = 0L
    Ack Policy= 0L
    Reserved  = 0L
    TXOP      = 0
###[ LLC ]###
       dsap      = 0xaa
       ssap      = 0xaa
       ctrl      = 3
###[ SNAP ]###
          OUI       = 0x0
          code      = 0x800
###[ IP ]###
             version   = 4L
             ihl       = 5L
             tos       = 0x0
             len       = None
             id        = 213
             flags     = 
             frag      = 0L
             ttl       = 128
             proto     = udp
             chksum    = None
             src       = 194.2.0.50
             dst       = 192.168.2.117
             \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
                sport     = domain
                dport     = 50648
                len       = None
                chksum    = None
###[ DNS ]###
                   id        = 64118
                   qr        = 1L
                   opcode    = QUERY
                   aa        = 0L
                   tc        = 0L
                   rd        = 1L
                   ra        = 1L
                   z         = 0L
                   rcode     = ok
                   qdcount   = 1
                   ancount   = 1
                   nscount   = 0
                   arcount   = 0
                   \qd        \
                    |###[ DNS Question Record ]###
                    |  qname     = 'www.youtube.com.'
                    |  qtype     = A
                    |  qclass    = IN
                   \an        \
                    |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
                    |  rrname    = 'www.youtube.com.'
                    |  type      = A
                    |  rclass    = IN
                    |  ttl       = 900
                    |  rdlen     = 4
                    |  rdata     = '192.168.2.100'
                   ns        = None
                   ar        = None
###[ Padding ]###
                      load      = '\xb2\x17\xa3\x8a'
```

I tried to check with a valid DNS response, I don't see any difference explaining my problem. I tried to modify the `ID` and `SC` fields, but it doesn't change anything. The `addr3` doesn't change.

Do you see an error explaining why the target doesn't receive it?

Comment: Have you checked what wiresharks sees on the intercepting machine? Your problem may be that datagram isn't send by the kernel stack.

Comment: You may also retry using the latest github version, it has lots of improves handling RadioTap headers (you won’t get the “notdecoded” part)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the length of your IP response is 'None'. That would not go well in processing. :) That's the obvious thing that stands out.  Also, your overall length at the top doesn't change, even though you've added data.

I'm not sure what sport/dport = domain means; I'm assuming those are port 53.

The IP ID fields should be generally be different in the query/response, but that wouldn't impact your results here.

Comment: No no no, scapy fills a lot of None fields when building the packet. It would have been better if he provided the result of `packet.show2()` (packet after being built). About the top you are right. He may set it to None so that scaly handles it